# How do I test autoconf's AC_REPLACE_FUNCS?

Tags: autotools, autoconf, automake

Say I have in my configure.ac

```
AC_REPLACE_FUNCS(getopt_long)
```

And I have getopt_long.h and getopt_long.c in my src directory. How would I go about forcing the HAVE_GETOPT_LONG to end up as 0 and getopt_long.c to be compiled along with everything else for testing purposes?

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do. Are you trying to replace the system `getopt_long` with your own implementation?

Comment: You're right. My question wasn't very clear. It's a getopt_long shim for systems without it. I wanted to test if it worked on a system *with* getopt_long. So I wanted a way to get autoconf to think it's not available. Is it possible do you know?

Comment: You mean, just once to make sure it works, or permanently because you want to write an automated test for your getopt_long implementation?

Comment: Just once to check it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this is the best way to go about it, since you would be including a `getopt_long` symbol in your executable that was also linked to the C standard library including a `getopt_long` symbol. The two symbols might not be able to be resolved correctly. However, you could try editing `config.h` manually and removing the `#define HAVE_GETOPT_LONG`.

A better approach might be to write code something like this:

```
#ifdef HAVE_GETOPT_LONG
inline
#endif
int
getopt_long_wrapper (int argc, char * const *argv, const char *shortopts,
                     const struct option *longopts, int *indexptr)
{
#ifdef HAVE_GETOPT_LONG
    return getopt_long (argc, argv, shortopts, longopts, indexptr);
#else
    /* your replacement function here */
#endif
}
```

Then if you removed the `HAVE_GETOPT_LONG` definition, there would be no conflict of symbols.

Comment: Isn't `config.h` auto-generated?

Comment: The post is asking about a way to temporarily test the situation. It's fine to edit an auto generated file for that.